# Market Making constant volatility assumption

Tags: high-frequency, market-microstructure, algorithmic-trading, market-making

I have read a few papers on market making and all(nearly) assume that the stock follows a brownian motion with no drift and constant volatility.These assumptions seems un-intuitive to me because of intraday volatility and garch effects.

I also downloaded some free tick by tick data of EURUSD from internet and ran the market making models of avellanda and stoikov  on it and the backtest results were quite poor.

Can any practitioner or anyone provide some tips or methods to adjust the volatility for my project ,any reference material would also be appreciated.

Comment: Hi : The authors probably assume that because there are so many things going on in those market making models that  assuming constant volatility, makes things somewhat easier. I don't know if it's useful but here's a possibly relevant paper. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325973445_Predictability_and_herding_of_bourse_volatility_An_econophysics_analogue. Other well known people in econophysics  are bouchaud, doyne farmer, gueant, rama cont and lehalle.  I don't know if they build intraday volatility models but you could check if they have websites to see if there's anything useful.

Comment: I tried modelling volatility as a garch process and also used other variants of garch ,still not one success.God its tough to make a profitable strategy(forget about the sharpe).

Comment: I have never been a marketmaker. But my impression is that, buying at the bid and selling at the ask it is not difficult to make money a decent percentage of the time. And the typical marketmaker in FX or stocks does not use fancy models but common sense and rules of thumb (options is a different story). What am I missing?

Comment: Not a single options trader on the planet thinks that volatility is constant.  It goes up and down like any other market variable.  How can any paper think it’s  constant

Comment: Can you suggest some other approaches to model volatility.Have tried garch and its variants with very poor results(better than constant volatility though). I know Stochastic volatility,haven't implemented it though.Also that i have only eurusd data may be there are volatility models specific to currencies which fit better.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on what your objective is? It might be convenient to assume volatility is constant if that is not your main priority, but in other cases it is critical to make it stochastic. Avellaneda and Stoikov's model seems theoretical in nature and the objective is rather to identify the main parameters that affect a market making strategy and how they impact PnL and the market, not an implementable model for someone to make money by simply applying it.

Comment: I was aggregating literature on market making, comparing models with backtest results for a project(maybe a paper later). I had tried and tested several but none had any good results.So i was looking for potential solutions as i have no practical experience in this.

Comment: @dm63 Can you suggest some models for modelling volatility particularly for currencies.

Comment: This looks useful a a glance. It's a little old but old school isn't necessarily a bad thing.  The more current topic research wise is "realized volatility". http://bibliotecadigital.fgv.br/dspace/bitstream/handle/10438/424/000090827.pdf;jsessionid=29692A59A86CF040385CED268BAEA60E?sequence=1

Answer (score 1):

That's true that in market making papers, like [Dealing with the Inventory Risk. A solution to the market making problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3115) 2012 by Guéant, L and Fernandez-Tapia, the volatility is often taken as constant.

What does it means? indeed you have two nature of uncertainties on the table when you make the market:

- the **mark to maket value of your inventory**. from a quantitative viewpoint on market making, the volatility is the proxy that your inventories goes against you. The volatility is a way to mesure the expected value of your inventory in the future.
- the **probability that other market participants will trade with you**, that leads to two effects: it allows to reduce your inventory (reacting to an anticipation of risk, thanks to your expectation of the volatility), or it could inflate your inventory towards more imbalance in an undesired solution (this is typically measure the *adverse selection risk*, that very often practitioners call *toxicity of the flow*).

They are very different in nature. If you know something about future prices, for instance thanks to a calendar (some economic numbers will be disclosed during the trading day, at 14:30 for Europe, but you do not know if they will be positive or not): **put this information in your volatility model**. It will naturally tell to the optimizer that you have to reduce your inventory before 2.30pm.

If you have a directional information on the price, for instance a News has just been disclosed about a patent issued by a company (think about the announce of Pfizer 's covid vaccine), it is affecting the flow of other participants in the direction of the information: if your quotes do not adjust, they will be hit a bad way. They you have to put this in your model of the probability of being lifted (that is often an point process with asymmetric intensities on the bid and ask side).